# Hampton Bay Windward II ceiling fan with light

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I took down a Hampton Bay Ceiling fan with light by untwisting the stem. The 4 wires for the controller got torn. Where do they go to fix the fan part? light works when hooked up to power.

Comment: Do you have a model number, photos of the fan's labeling, or any documentation for this fan?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you.

Comment: The wires might have been torn out of the controller PCB or fan internals.

Comment: How do I attach a picture of the fan with wires going nowhere ( because I tore them getting the fan down)?